# Purge procedure getting deadlocked with normal CRUD operations of application

Tags: sql-server

I have a procedure which runs every midnight to delete expired rows from the database. During the job my application gets deadlock error when it tries to perform insert or update on the table. What should be the best way to avoid deadlock?

I have millions of record to delete every midnight, which I am deleting in a batch of 1000 rows at a time.

@batch=1000
WHILE @rowCount > 0
        BEGIN TRY

```
        DELETE TOP (@batch) FROM application
            WHERE job_id IN (SELECT ID FROM JOB 
                                WHERE  process_time < @expiryDate)
            OR prev_job_id IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].JOB
                                WHERE  process_time < @expiryDate)
        SELECT @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
        END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    //some code here...
```

Comment: Start by figuring out what's locking it. Disk speed, RAM, and table usage are things that can be a factor

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide more info!!!!! Show us code or what you've tried

Comment: @DiegoS : Below is the procedure I have

batch=1000
WHILE rowCount > 0
  BEGIN TRY

   DELETE TOP (batch) FROM application
    WHERE job_id IN (SELECT ID FROM JOB 
                                 WHERE  process_time < expiryDate)
    OR prev_job_id IN (SELECT ID FROM JOB
                                 WHERE  process_time < expiryDate)
   SELECT rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
            END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  //some code here...

Statement getting deadlocked 
Insert into application () values ()

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code. The question can be better formated than a comment.

Comment: Last time I had this issue, it was on SQL-Server 2008. I tried the `WITH NO LOCK` command, but it didn't work because Microsoft disabled it (apparently it was causing indexes corruption)... Which version are you using ?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. : Using SQL-Server 2012